# Dictionary for Take Profit and Stop Loss on Stock Positions

Tags: python, dictionary, finance, stock

Let's say I have a dictionary (current_price) that constantly updates the values as the latest price of a given stock (keys).
Above it I already have a dictionary that saves the entry price for the given stock.
Additionally, I have a Take Profit and Stop Loss set at a certain number.

```
entry_price = {'SPY': 350, 'QQQ': 250}
current_price = {'SPY': 367, 'QQQ': 220}

TP = 15
SL = -10

current_pl = {'SPY': ???, 'QQQ': ???}
```

How would I need to loop through the `current_price` dictionary to check if the `current_pl` is more than 15 or less than -10. If none of them are that number, then obviously keep the position open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As follows

**Code**

```
# Setup
entry_price = {'SPY': 350, 'QQQ': 250}
current_price = {'SPY': 367, 'QQQ': 220}

TP = 15
SL = -10

# Use dictionary comprehension to update current_pl dictionary
current_pl = {k:(v-entry_price[k]) for k, v in current_price.items()}

# Simple loop to check thresholds
for k, v in current_pl.items():
if v >= TP:
    print(f'Profit    - Symbol {k} Profit {v}')
elif v <= SL:
    print(f'Stop Loss - Symbol {k} Loss {v}')

# Open positions after applying thresholds
open_positions = {k:current_price[k] for k, v in current_pl.items() if v < TP and v > SL}
print(f'Open Positions {open_positions}')
```

**Output**

```
Profit    - Symbol SPY Profit 17
Stop Loss - Symbol QQQ Loss -30
Open Positions {}
```